# What is custom flair?

Tags: discussion, flair

I hear this from time to time but I have no idea of what it is.

Could someone please tell me.

I [still](https://askubuntu.com/users/10698/alvar/flair) don't get what it is or how I should use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just a nice and stylish way of *showing off*.

Flair exists to let everyone else know about your brilliant Stack Exchange profile. You should put it on your website, your page on the Ubuntu wiki, and your vest that you wear at work.

[image]
*Brian, for example, has 37 pieces of flair (and a terrific smile)*

The URL of your flair is `http://askubuntu.com/users/flair/0.png`, where `0` is your user id. You can customize your piece of flair by adding `?theme=dark`, (or `clean`, `hotdog`). And you can include this image anywhere you like.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but are you referring to [StackImage 2](https://stackapps.com/questions/2400/stackimage-2-create-your-own-unique-custom-flair)? It's a tool that allows you to create your very own custom flair by dragging-and-dropping components onto a grid. You can customize all aspects of the flair, including width, height, color, font, etc. Then you can generate an image URL, HTML markup, or JavaScript code that can be embedded on your website.

Example:

http://stackimage2.quickmediasolutions.com/4dd2fde77a2ca/askubuntu/10698